# How to draw a Dotted Outline on a image according to its shape on touch it?

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I need to draw a dotted outline on a image according to its shape. how to draw the path according to the object shape? Attached an sample image .
[image]

Please suggest some idea

Comment: `Canvas#drawPath`